# Why is a field of my entity class null?

Tags: jpa

I have these two entities in a one to many relation:

```
public class Category implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Short id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "categoryId")
    private Collection<Product> productCollection;

    ...

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Product> getProductCollection() {
        return productCollection;
    }

    ...
```

and

```
public class Product implements Serializable {

    ...

    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Category categoryId;

    ...
```

generated with NetBeans. The problem is that when the method getProductCollection() is called by the ControllerServlet the Collection of Product is null.

```
    @Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String userPath = request.getServletPath();
    Category selectedCategory;
    Collection<Product> categoryProducts;

    // if category page is requested
    if (userPath.equals("/category")) {
        // get categoryId from request
        String categoryId = request.getQueryString();

        if (categoryId != null) {

            // get selected category
            selectedCategory = categoryFacade.find(Short.parseShort(categoryId));

            // place selected category in request scope
            request.setAttribute("selectedCategory", selectedCategory);

            // get all products for selected category
            categoryProducts = selectedCategory.getProductCollection();

            // place category products in request scope
            request.setAttribute("categoryProducts", categoryProducts);
        }
```

[Notice the null value of productCollection when other fields has been yet initialized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16N00.png)

Edit 1: I declared the categoryFacade in the ControllerServlet applying the @EJB annotation

```
public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    private CategoryFacade categoryFacade;
```

Edit 2: Here is the persistence.xml document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="AffableBeanPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/affablebean</jta-data-source>
        <properties/>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Edit 3: I'm using TomEE 7.0.2

Comment: How is `categoryFacade` initialized in the servlet?

Comment: I used the EJB annotation applied to the declaration of categoryFacade

Comment: Do you have `transaction-type="JTA"` in persistence.xml descriptor? You should add these info to the question by editing it

Comment: Yes, i have `transaction-type="JTA"`

Comment: Your code runs fine on GlassFish 4.1. The EJB Facade is correctly injected into the servlet and the variable `categoryProducts` gets fed with the child categoryProduct values when method `getProductCollection` is invoked. Probably you have forgot to add some key information in your question